# schedule AppEngine mapreduce jobs from compute engine

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to schedule AppEngine mapreduce's from a compute engine server?

I have the production app running on AppEngine, and what I am trying to do is to kick off MapReduce jobs and track the status of them from a compute engine instance, once a MR job is done, do some extra work on compute engine instance.

I did some search online and couldn't find many similar stories. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your mapreduce job in python code, you can make a servlet that triggers the mapreduce.

```
from mapreduce import control
class ComputeMRHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        control.start_map(
            name='Mapreduce Name',
            reader_spec='mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader',
            handler_spec='my_mapper_function',
            mapper_parameters={'entity_kind': 'my_datastore.DataRecord'},
        )
```

Then just call the above handler via a web request to your GAE server.

Doing stuff at the end is a bit harder. You can either write something on your compute engine to poll the GAE app, waiting for it to finish.

Or you can explore the "pipeline" library https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines , which allows you to sequence a series of operations (namely, running the mapreduce, and then later running a "completion" code block). To do that you should really understand pipeline, but the code is basically:

```
class MyCompletionHandlerPipeline(fixed_pipelines.Pipeline):
    def run(self, results):
        # Request some handler on your GCE instance that tells it:
        # "hey we're done, go process your extra work now"
        pass

class MapreduceAndCompletionPipeline(fixed_pipelines.Pipeline):
    def run(self):
        results = yield MyMapReducePipeline(parameters)
        # the dependency on results ensures it runs after MyMapReducePipeline
        yield MyCompletionHandlerPipeline(results)
```